# Google Calendar API and php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I have used Google calendar api but the user authentication porocess shows error and i did not knwo what is the reason for this error i strictly follow the instruction of the google developer code Please give me the answer.
Here is my code for authentication

```
<?php
require 'src/Google/autoload.php';
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-api-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));

/**
* Returns an authorized API client.
* @return Google_Client the authorized client object
*/
function getClient() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    // Load previously authorized credentials from a file.
    $credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

        // Store the credentials to disk.
        if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
        printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
    }
    return $client;
}

/**
* Expands the home directory alias '~' to the full path.
* @param string $path the path to expand.
* @return string the expanded path.
*/
function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
    $homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
    if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
        $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
    }
    return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

The output shows the error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Invalid code' in C:\xampp\htdocs\lapi\odesk8\google_calendar\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php:88 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lapi\odesk8\google_calendar\src\Google\Client.php(128): Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('', false) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\lapi\odesk8\google_calendar\test.php(33): Google_Client->authenticate('') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lapi\odesk8\google_calendar\test.php(66): getClient() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lapi\odesk8\google_calendar\src\Google\Auth\OAuth2.php on line 88

Comment: I don't think php resolves $HOME: `define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-api-quickstart.json');` - nvm. didn't see `expandHomeDirectory` in that wall of code

Comment: What you suggest to do ?

Comment: check if php can read the contents of the file defined as `CLIENT_SECRET_PATH`

Comment: Will you give me a better solution or any link ?

Comment: no, but I'll describe it a bit. According to your stacktrace and [OAuth2.php line 88](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php#L88), the `Google_Auth_Exception` with this particular exception message (`Invalid code`) is thrown _if and only if_ the `$code` var is emtpy - without knowledge on my part about OAuth2 at all, I simply recommend you check that php is actually able to find and read said file (`client_secret.json`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sample code you provided reads from STDIN (`$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));`) IF `~/.credentials/calendar-api-quickstart.json` is not readable or does not exists

I assume you do not pipe in the auth-code and the samplecode is unable to find `~/.credentials/calendar-api-quickstart.json`, which results in the Exception since it gets no auth-code